# MUL instruction Assembly 32-bit into 64-bit

Tags: assembly, x86

Use the MUL instruction to multiply two unsigned 32-bit operands, P and Q, located in memory and place result in the 64-bit memory location W.

It's not possible, right?

I tried:

```
    mov eax, dword[P]
    mul dword[Q]
    mov qword[W] edx:eax
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* service

Comment: what did the intel documentation say and what part did you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just have to do the store in two parts:

```
    mov dword[W], eax
    mov dword[W+4], edx
```